# Word for a person/organization who has jurisdiction over something

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that conveys that an organization (but more generally could include a person) has jurisdiction over something. What would I call, in general, the organization which has jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2):

***Authority***

From [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/authority.html):

> An agency or body created by a government to perform a specific
> function, such as environment management, power generation, or tax
> collection.

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/authority):

> *(often authorities)* A person or organization having political or
> administrative power and control:
>
> health authorities issued a
> worldwide alert
>
> Apart from the politicians and
> the health authorities, economists are also worried.
>
> These, then, are
> the various powers under which governmental authorities may act.
>
> They
> are also calling for powers to allow authorities to intervene to
> protect young people who are at risk from drugs.
>
> **Synonyms** :
>
> **officials**, **officialdom**, the people in charge, the government,
> **the administration**, **the establishment, the bureaucracy**, the system;
> the police
>
> *informal* the powers that be, the (men in) suits, Big
> Brother

Answer (score 1):

You could say they're the [**administrator**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+administrator):

> a person responsible for running a business, organization, etc.
>
> **synonyms:** manager, director, executive, controller, head, chief, leader, governor, superintendent, supervisor; boss
>
> *"he became the team's top administrator in 1973"*

Similarly, you could call them the **administration**, depending on exactly what you're talking about.